# Set App Pool recycle time with PowerShell trouble

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to set **two** specific times to recycle my App Pools in IIS.

In the GUI, if you want to set multiple specific times you enter it like so `00:15, 04:30`.

Below is my PowerShell. It only sets the first time - 00:15. Unfortunately, no error is happening, and so there is no error to post.

Why is this only setting the first time? I am using `New-ItemProperty` over `Set-ItemProperty`.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$RecycleTimes = @("00:15", "04:30")
$PrivateMemory = 1468006     
$sites = Get-ChildItem 'IIS:\AppPools\' <# | Where-Object { $_.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.TotalMilliseconds -gt 1 } #>

    foreach ($s in $sites) {
        # Turn off Fixed Intervals recylcing setting
        Set-ItemProperty $s.PSPath -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 0.00:00:00
        # Set application pool recycle time
        Clear-ItemProperty $s.PSPath -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
        foreach ($RecycleTime in $RecycleTimes) {
            New-ItemProperty $s.PSPath -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$RecycleTime}
        }
        #Set Private memory usage
        Set-ItemProperty $s.PSPath -Name recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory -Value $PrivateMemory
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the powershell command line code you provided on my local machine and can successfully set two recycle times. This means there is nothing wrong with your code.

[image]

You can try to use the following basic powershell command line code to set multiple specific recycling application pool time for the default website, see if it works.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value="00:15"}
New-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value="04:30"}
```

Comment: What version of Windows? Did you run the code, open IIS, and just see both times? Your snippet is just a modified version of my code. Thanks much!

Comment: I am using windows 10 Enterprise. As you said, I ran the code you provided, opened IIS and saw that two specific times have been successfully set.